# Is it possible to hire Wolgraff if my personality is Priest?

Tags: divinity-original-sin

I've set my male character's personality to none or knight (I'm not sure) and my female character's personality to priest. When I try to hire Wolgraff my female character responds:

> He'll consider no such thing, we'll not align ourselves with a brigand
>   and that is final!

Is there a workaround for this? I understand the RP value of this particular dialog but Wolgraff is not evil so I thought I would be able to hire him.

Comment: there is no option at that point to initiate an argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a solution to this problem. You have to unlink the character that says no and send him away. Using the other character you can hire Wolgraff. You can now relink with the other character with no problems. A bit immersion breaking but alas.